# How to move not copy files into iTunes

Tags: itunes

I have a folder containing all my Music, Movies etc. This contains various formats of music file, including some that iTunes cannot play (i.e. flac and oggs) but a lot of mp3s.

I'd like to have iTunes import all the formats it can play, moving those files into the iTunes Media folder, but leaving behind the files in formats it isn't able to play.  That way I can decide what to do with those files later, but the rest of my media is managed through iTunes.

The option in iTunes preferences copies files into the iTunes Media folder, but leaves behind a duplicate.

Am I missing something, or is there a trick to this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I let iTunes copy all the media.  Then I could search for all files that contained .mp3 in the source folder, and move them to trash.

Comment: -1 - why?  What is wrong with this?  It worked for me, and it was my question.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes never deletes original files. But you could use a simple script to remove the mp3/aac files (which are supported by iTunes).

But if you uncheck "Keep iTunes Media folder organized", files will be read from their original location without being copied;

Answer (score 1):

I would import all with iTunes and let it make copies. In the Finder, Arrange the folder by Kind and Sort by Kind as well. Then it should be easy to pick out the files you know iTunes did import and delete them with one selection. Assuming you have OSX 10.8.